# Set session value for text fields in jsp in spring mvc application

Tags: spring, jsp

**JSP page**

```
    <h1>${name}</h1>
    <input name="name" value="${name}" type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save_form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveQuotation(@ModelAttribute("FormData") SampleDO sampledo, 
          BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

        session.setAttribute("name", sampledo.getName());

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:index");
    }
```

**The session value from  the controller is set**

*1. the data in h1 tag print in jsp page*

*2. but the data in text field doesnot print the value*

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n2Xy.png)

**This image shows the session value is set to the value attribute but not displaying in html**

Comment: Can you share working code on github, for example? Now it's very difficult to say why it isn't working.

Comment: I have added a image how i got the **output**

Comment: How does it help? In you question you have `h1` and `input` tags, but in photo there are not present.

Comment: You seem to be using AngularJS. The input has `data-ng-model="name"`. So its value is the value of the name property for the enclosing controller $scope.

Comment: Thanks guys ...........it works with ng-model="${name}" @JBNizet